# Setting Bootstrap collapse to have element open by default based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I'm working on making an FAQ page and have a bootstrap collapse with the categories of questions as the collapse titles and the questions as the body.
I'm using the same collapse for both the index and question display pages and I am passing a local variable `local: { display: boolean }` to differentiate.

I loop through the categories collection to make each table row
`<% @categories.each_with_index do |category, index| %>`

I have conditionals in the class and aria-expanded of the trigger element:
`class='<%= "collapsed" if !display || category != @question.category %>'`
`aria-expanded='<%= category == @question.category %>'`
And in the class of the target
`class='collapse <%= "show" if display && category == @question.category %>'`

The page loads with the correct row open but it doesn't close when triggered.

Comment: I think this is because you have hard coded the display value and not changing its value when triggering.

Answer (score 7):

Everything is described in the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accessibility)

To achieve what you need, you have to:

1. For buttons/headers:

   1. set `data-toggle="collapse"`
   2. if the content of the target has to be hidden, then set `aria-expanded="false"`
   3. if the content of the target has to be displayed, then set `aria-expanded="true"`
2. For the targets:

   1. set `class="collapse"` if the target has to be hidden
   2. set `class="collapse show"` if the target has to be displayed

Here is an example

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Toggle first element</a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Toggle second element</button>
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse show multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        First element content (displayed by the default)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Second element content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked in my Angular App as well! (I first had the id on two <div>s because I copied it into a new component, that's why it seemed not working.)